# JQuery mobile multiselect (dialog list) option limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to limit the amount of selectable options on a multi select dialog (JQuery Mobile), but really can't seam to get it working as expected.

I have made a JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/xdJJg/5/

As you can see even though the limit is 4, 5 is selectable. Also if you click on an option previous to another one, it will remove both.

Have tried a few different ways to do this, cant seam to figure it out.

```
    <select id="test1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Sportbooks</option>
        <option value="1">Test1</option>
        <option value="2">Test2</option>
        <option value="3">Test3</option>
        <option value="4">Test4</option>
        <option value="5">Test5</option>
        <option value="6">Test6</option>
        <option value="7">Test7</option>
        <option value="8">Test8</option>
        <option value="9">Test9</option>
        <option value="10">Test10</option>
        <option value="11">Test11</option>
        <option value="12">Test12</option>
        <option value="13">Test13</option>
        <option value="14">Test13</option>
        <option value="15">Test13</option>
        <option value="16">Test13</option>
        <option value="17">Test13</option>
        <option value="18">Test13</option>
        <option value="19">Test13</option>
        <option value="20">Test13</option>
    </select>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test1").change(function () {
            $(this).find("option:selected")
            if ($(this).find("option:selected").length > 4) {
                $(this).find("option").removeAttr("selected");
                $(this).val(arr);
            } else {
                arr = new Array();
                $(this).find("option:selected").each(function (index, item) {
                    arr.push($(item).val());
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope someone can help us out, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is due to the fact that you are using .length on an array which starts at an index of 0. So in order to limit to 4 you want to use >= 4 and that will fix that portion. I am looking into fixing the other issue of how it removes more than one when you select an item above a checked item.